# Does unsealing a class cause a runtime or compile time break?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project that involves a lot of immutable classes.  We are interested in marking these classes as sealed, but are concerned that if we ever decide to "unseal" a class at a later time that it will cause a runtime or compile time error for the customers of our API.  Is there any merit to this concern, or will unsealing a class cause no runtime / compile time issues?

Comment: I'll be disappointed if Jon Skeet doesn't complain about the idea of unsealing a class that was not designed for inheritance.  If you aren't designing these classes with inheritance in mind, then things might break later when you unseal them.  And if you are designing them for inheritance, there is no need to seal them.

Comment: I would do a quick test if I were you :)

Comment: I did run a quick, simple test, which did not cause a compile-time or runtime break, but I didn't consider something like reflection (mentioned below in one of the answers).  That's the sort of thing I'm concerned about, is some clever code I haven't considered that might break.

As to why we might unseal a class....hopefully we don't.  I'd like to know the consequences ahead of time though, should this happen.

Comment: I can think of scenarios where initial sealing might be desirable until inheritance is required. I have some libraries that make use of the implied 'sealed' knowledge to optimise some dynamic (run-time) processing (e.g. the knowledge that there is never going to be a derived class).

Comment: Keep in mind that by the nature of reflection it should adapt to the reality of the actual class at run-time... so unless someone has made code that performs reflection *expecting* a sealed class, that should not be a problem... and altho someone could write code like that, I think it kinda goes against the whole idea of using reflection in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsealing a class will not cause any additional compile time errors.  It is possible for unsealing a class to allow previously uncompilable code to compile, but not the other way around.

It is possible to cause a number of runtime issues but I think they would be pretty rare because it would require the consumer to be inspecting the type metadata.  For instance it would be possible for a user to throw if a type was unsealed but I'm not sure that is a major concern.

Comment: Do you know what those runtime exceptions might be?  I'd like to get the possible runtime exceptions documented for future reference.

Comment: @JadeMason, no because it would be very dependent on what the user chose to throw in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the sealed attribute from your class in an updated version of your framework will merely allow them to derive from your class whereas they previously couldn't do so. As long as your updated version does not require your clients to derive from your class, I can't think of any problem.

Another effect of unsealing the class is that the runtime won't be able to optimize away some virtual function calls, but that's not going to cause any problems either.